# How to fix typeError using crypto in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I am creating an endpoint for a `sign up/login` system and password encryption I chose to use hash method. However, I get the error.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined.
```

Code to create the hash method.

```js
const getHash = function (password, salt) {
 return crypto
  .pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 100000, 256, 'sha256')
  .toString('hex')
}
```

Code to create a new user and call the has method to encrypt password.

```js
const addNewUser = function(user, done) {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(64); 
    const hash = getHash(user.password, salt); 

    const sql = 'INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'
    
    let values = [user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email, hash, salt.toString('hex')];

    db.run(
        sql, 
        values, 
        function(err){
        
        if(err) return done(err,null);
        
        return done(null, this.lastID);
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what the value of user.password is?

Comment: Yes i have added in a 'console.log(user.password)' and when run it seems valid but still getting the error